# Have I been using Jquery.ready() incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, turbolinks

With respect to Jquery ready event block, the docs say:

> The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the  attribute. If load must be used, either do not use .ready() or use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event handlers to the window or to more specific items, like images.

and this

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

In my coffeescript files for Rails, I tend to follow this pattern:

```
$ ->
  $("body.controller_name").ready ->
    $(".button_group").change (evt) ->
      alert("do something")
```

and if I need to delegate a binding for an element that will be created and is not in the initial html, I tend to do this.

```
$ ->
  $("body.controller_name").ready ->

    $('.button_group').change (evt) ->
      alert("do something")


    $(document).on 'change', '.button_group', (event) ->
      alert("do something")
```

When checking out turbolinks.jquery gem, I encountered this note:

```
 /* BAD: don't bind 'document' events while inside $()! */
 $(function() {
   $(document).on('click', 'button', function() { ... })
 });
```

So It leaves me wondering, have I been doing it wrong all along?
Should I avoid using `$(document).on()` inside the ready block?
If so, other than possible conflict with turbolinks.jquery is there a reason WHY this is wrong?

So what is the correct pattern?  I familiar with waiting for assets to load by using the load block instead of the ready block, but I'm not sure i'm aware of what I've been doing wrong all this time.

Comment: The document.ready is needed if you add your scripts in the head, to wait for the DOM to load. You could simply load everything in the body, just before the closing tag.

Comment: I definately don't do that.  I generally am programming in a Rails or similar environment, so I'm using an asset pipeline which includes my coffeescript files post-compiled and included in the header.  I  am asking specifically, in the context of this practice, what is the problem of including `$(document).on('event', 'selector', function () { ... })` inside the jquery.ready event block?

Comment: Just checked the TurboLinks docs, not sure why it's important, is it giving any issues? I haven't heard of such bad practice, but maybe TurboLink might trigger the ready event more than once...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no.

There i no reason to avoid binding events on the document level in the `ready` event, if you need them.

However, you should avoid binding delegates on the document level, if you can help it. You should use an element that is as close as possible to the element where the event will occur. Whenever the event occurs inside the element where you bound it, it has to check if the element where the event occured matches the selector, so if you bind the delegate on the document level, that work has to be done for every such event occuring anywhere in the page.

The `live` method did bind delegates on the document level, and now that method is removed from jQuery and replaced by the `delegate` method (which is now replaced by the `on` method), because you should generally bind delegates on a smaller scope.

---

The quote from the documentation doesn't talk about what you do in the `ready` event, it talks about the `<body onload="">` attribute. You shouldn't use that when you are using the `ready` or `load` events in jQuery.

Comment: ["As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method."](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: @muistooshort: I see how you would be confused... I corrected my spelling mistake.

Comment: SO, I've adjusted my bindings with `$(selector).on(event, selector, function)`  to all be outside the jQuery ready event, AND to bind as close as possible to an existing element.

I still need to re-enable turbolinks and see whether this all works as expected.  

The quote from the document is to bread in conjunction with the quote from https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks



Where  it refers to the  anonymous style jquery ready block

Comment: @AshleyRaiteri: The quote from the jQuery documentation and the quote from the jquery.turbolinks page are talking about different things. The jQuery quote is about the `onload` attribute, while the jquery.turbolinks quote is about how Turolinks changes loading of the page. As Turbolinks takes over how the page is loaded, the ready event doesn't work as it would normally, so you have to do some things differently.